# Complex matrices: looking for homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, determinant

> Let $\mathbb{C}$ denote the complex numbers, and let $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ be the ring of $2$ by $2$ matrices with real entries. Define a function $f:\mathbb{C} \to M_2(\mathbb{R})$ by
>
> $ f(a+bi) = \left[ \begin{align} a && {-b} \\ b && a \end{align} \right]$
>
> Prove that $f$ is an injective homomorphism of rings. Is it an isomorphism?

So that is my problem. Okay, so I don't really know what $f(a)$ and $f(bi)$ are, so it is kinda hard to show it is homomorphic.

So I tried this(don't want to do matrices they take forever. Read element break as comma, and line break as semi colon like in matlab):

$f(a+bi)=f(c+di) \to [a,-b;b,a] = [c,-d;d,c]$ take det and get $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$

so since these matrices are equal, then $a=c, d=b$, hence $f$ is an injective homomorphism.

Now for isomorphism we need surjection.

Comment: Why take determinant? If two matrices are equal, then what can you say about their corresponding entries?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Entries are equal?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan To show surjection, I need to take some element matrix [a,b;c,d] right? But this matrix certainly can't be made from this function if $a\ne d$, so it isn't surjective right?

Comment: This is correct - you can find matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ that are NOT of the shape $\left( \begin{align} a && {-b} \\ b && a \end{align} \right)$. @user142198 - I still miss your verification that the map is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: @NickyHekster I actually don't know how I can show that here, I get that I want $f(a)+f(bi)=f(a+bi)$, but I don't know what $f(a)$ and $f(bi)$ are. Can I have a hint?

Comment: Note that $f(a) = f(a+0i)$ and $f(bi) = f(0+bi)$