# How to find an injective ring homomorphism from $S$ to $M_n(R)$,where S is a commutative unitary ring as well as a free module over its subring $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, free-modules

Suppose $S$ is a commutative unitary ring and $R$ is a subring of $S$,naturally S becomes a $R$-module.

To prove: If S is a free $R$-module over R of rank $n$,then there is a ring isomorphism between $S$ and a subring of matrix ring $M_n(R)$.

Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a basis of module S,then $\forall s\in S,s=a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n$,where all coefficients $a_1,\dots,a_n\in R$ are unique.

It is natural to define a mapping $\varphi:S\to M_n(R),s=a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & & & \\ & a_2 & & \\& & \ddots & \\ & & & a_n \end{pmatrix}$.

But how to prove it is a ring homomorphism?It is obvious that the mapping preserves addition.And if it preserves multiplication,it preserves the multiplicative identity,too.

So here is my problem:How to prove this mapping preserves multiplication?Or my definition is wrong to make it impossible?

Edit:Due to this [case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844418/complex-matrices-looking-for-homomorphism),I believe it is hard to construct such mapping,since we know very little about the ring.Perhaps non-constructive methods are needed to solve this problem.

Comment: This won't work in general, think e.g. of $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb R$. You started well, by fixing a basis. What does multiplication by $s$ do with the basis elements? Maybe it helps making this explicit for $\mathbb C$ first

Comment: It seems like $x_ix_j=0$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: Yes,but what about $a_i b_i x_i^2$ in the multiplication $s_1 s_2$?

Comment: @doetoe Did you mean this [case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844418/complex-matrices-looking-for-homomorphism)?

Comment: @ysouserious that is the solution, but how do you find it? If you understand that, the general case will follow.

Comment: @doetoe I just searched for complex ring and matrix representation.But I still don't know how to deal with the general case since I know little about the ring $S$,more precisely,what are the multiplies of generators like $x_i x_j$?In $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$,we know how generators $\{1,i\}$ act on each other and themselves.But what about the general ring $S$?

Comment: @YSouSerious you don't know it concretely, but you know something interesting: multiplication by any element $s\in S$ transforms any basis element into a linear combination of basis elements. Moreover, this is an $R$-linear mapping: $s(x + y) = sx + sy$ and $s(rx) = rsx$. This means that multiplication by an element of $S$ can be represented by a matrix over $R$. Can you take it from there? It may help to work it out for $\mathbb C$ first.